# Is the fact that these sets cannot exist a consequence of Russell's paradox?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Some time ago I asked why a given collection of objects could not be a set (something to do with abstract algebra). I got three answers, one was close to the Russell's paradox, two other explanations involved cardinality. But I am wondering if the answers involving cardinality are simply consequences of Russell's paradox?

The two statements I got was:

> But the class of all sets of a given nonzero cardinality is not a set.

..

> Since the class of sets equipotent to $K\setminus F$ and disjoint from
>   $F$ is not a set, we're done.

I have two questions:

1. Are these two statements equivalent?
2. When proving these statements, do you use Russell's paradox, so in a sense the are equivalent to Russell's paradox? (Alternatively, does Russell's paradox imply them?)

Answer (score 3):

Where are we proving things? This matters a lot, because different choices of axioms for set theory will give different answers. According to the standard set of axioms - ZFC - both statements are true; however, in (say) NF, another set of axioms, they are false! So to show (in some system) that these aren't sets, we need to use some specific axioms in addition to Russell's paradox.

In ZFC, we use the axioms **replacement** and **separation**. Take for example the class $C$ of sets of cardinality 1. Then I can define a map from $C$ to the universe of all sets, sending $\{x\}$ to $x$. If $C$ were a set, then by replacement the image of $m$ - that is, the whole universe - would be a set. But separation, together with the argument of Russell's paradox, implies that the whole universe cannot be a set.

(Actually, replacement implies separation, so we only needed replacement, but whatever.)

---

Let me address the (non-)role of Foundation/Regularity here, based on the comments below.

Foundation sounds very relevant to questions of this sort, since Russell's paradox deals with self-containing sets. In particular, in many set theories without foundation (e.g. NF), there is a set-of-all-sets. So it is tempting to guess that, without foundation, we can't disprove the existence of a set of all sets.

However, it turns out that foundation is really a red herring here. It is easy to prove that there is no universal set in ZF minus foundation, as follows:

- Suppose a universal set $U$ existed.
- By Separation, we get the set $R=\{x: x\in U, x\not\in x\}$. Note that all we need here is that "$x\not\in x$" is a formula in the language of set theory - it doesn't matter what sort of formula it is, the Separation scheme applies to *all* formulas.
- Now the usual Russell argument goes through. If $R\in R$, then $R\not\in R$; this is immediate (and more generally shows that for any set $A$, the set $R_A=\{X: X\in A, X\not\in X\}$ is not an element of $A$, although it is a set by Separation). More substantively, we know by assumption that $R\in U$ (since our assumption was that everything is in $U$); so if $R\not\in R$, that means $R\in U$ and $R\not\in R$, so $R\in R$.
- So we have a contradiction; and this means that our initial assumption - that a universal set exists - was incorrect.

Note that this is a proof *inside the theory ZF minus Foundation*. I'm not arguing "If there is a universal set, then ZF minus Foundation is inconsistent;" I'm saying "ZF minus Foundation proves that there is no universal set." This proof inside ZF minus Foundation is a proof by contradiction, but that's fine.

Comment: I would think using union would be preferable to replacement - since it generalizes to larger cardinality better.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but I don't see how to do this with union. We could also use Foundation, as Tim Carson does - if $C$ is the class of sets which are equinumerous with $X$, and $a\in X$ with $a\not=C$, then let $C'=\{C\}\cup(X-\{a\})$. Then $C'\in C$ but $C\in C'$.

Comment: OH WOW, of course union works: taking the union of the set of, say, sets of size 3 yields the whole universe. Derp :P

Comment: @user119615: And since there are models of ZFC minus Foundation plus its negation, Tim Carson's claim that every proof that there is no set of all singletons must use Foundation is incorrect since Noah's proof does not.

Comment: This is not strictly correct.  You are using "ZFC is consistent" in your proof.  Or your using the vague statement "Russel's paradox can't happen".  Neither of these are axioms or theorems in ZFC.   (For some reason I just got the notification of this answer...)

Comment: What I meant with needing foundation is that, if you try to prove it in ZFC, you will need foundation.  If I remove foundation from ZFC, I won't be able to prove that there is no set $U$ such that $\forall x, x \in U$.  Of course as @user21820 mentions there are set theories which contradict foundation, and you can still add a weaker version of foundation to them and end up being able to prove that there is no such $U$.

Comment: @TimCarson "If I remove foundation from ZFC, I won't be able to prove that there is no set $U$ such that $\forall x, x\in U$." I'm sorry, but that's completely incorrect. Separation alone proves that such a $U$ can't exist: supposing such a $U$ existed, apply Separation to $U$ using the formula "$x\not\in x$" and we get the set $R=\{x\in U: x\not\in x\}$. But now we can easily argue that both $R\in R$ and $R\not\in R$, and this yields a contradiction; so our initial assumption, that $U$ existed, is false. Foundation really isn't relevant here, even though it sounds like it would be.

Comment: To summarize: while the existence of such a $U$ contradicts Foundation, Foundation is **not needed** to show that such a $U$ exists. ZF minus Foundation proves that no such $U$ exists purely by invoking Separation. As to "You are using "ZFC is consistent" in your proof," no I'm not: my claim is e.g. "ZFC proves that the class of singletons is not a set," and this is true via the argument I give. ZFC's consistency has nothing to do with it; I've provided a proof *in ZFC* of the desired statement, so the statement "ZFC proves ---" is true, regardless of whether ZFC is consistent.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I was so confident with that idea.  Somehow I had it stuck in my head that the paradox only helped to guide us and not that it also gave us a path through proof by contradiction.  Your explanation was really helpful.

Comment: @TimCarson I'm glad it was helpful! In general, it's worth keeping in mind that each "paradox" in natural language/naive set theory/etc. can be viewed as showing that a class of theories (e.g. in this case the ones with full comprehension) are inconsistent. And often we can do better, and turn these into actually interesting impossibility proofs - e.g. once we have the diagonal lemma, the Liar paradox gives us Tarski's undefinability theorem, while a variation of it gives Godel's (first) incompleteness theorem.